# What does Array as Object mean in Basic4Android?

Tags: basic4android

```
SQL1.ExecNonQuery2("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(?,?,?)",Array As Object("def",3,4))
```

I don't seem to understand why the argument list in the above statement is declared in the form of Array as Object('xx','xx''xx').How is it exactly being converted into a list parameter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array As xxx is a shorthand syntax for declaring a new array and assigning the values.

```
Array As Object("def", 3, 4)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Dim arr As Object(3)
arr(0) = "def" : arr(1) = 3 : arr(1) = 4
```

Basic4android automatically wraps arrays as lists when needed. The items are not copied, it is the whole array that is wrapped in a list. Therefore the above code is valid as it creates an array which is then wrapped as a List.